# once a Boolean variable false don't return true in other cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I've got the following code

```
$(function(){

    var isValid = function(test_obj, element){
        if(!test_obj.val().length > 0){
            element.addClass('has-error');
            return false;
        }else{
            element.removeClass('has-error');
            return true;
        }
    };
    $('#rta_parties_form').submit(function(event){

        var formSubmit;

        formSubmit = isValid($('#rta_cl_fn'), $('#div_cl_fn'));
        formSubmit = isValid($('#rta_cl_ln'), $('#div_cl_ln'));
        formSubmit = isValid($('#rta_cl_ph'), $('#div_cl_ph'));
        formSubmit = isValid($('#rta_cl_mob'), $('#div_cl_mob'));

        if(!formSubmit){
            event.preventDefault();
        }else{
            alert('formSubmit successfully');
        }


    });
});
```

As you can see I'm using `formSubmit = isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_fn')`, `$('#div_cl_fn'));` on four different occasions. My issue: let's say in first 3 instances, it returns `false` but on the fourth instance, it returns `true`, then it will submit the form successfully?

Is there any way to check if any of those instances return `false` or set all the instances to `false` so form should not be submitted?

I know I can use nested `if` statements, but then, what is the point of using a function? I wanted to avoid using multiple `if` statements in my code. That's why I wrote the function; otherwise, I could have just used the function code in my actual code and set `formSubmit` to `false`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use an error counter that say "there are errors" and at the end of your code, you test if the counter is > 0. If yes, don't submit. Otherwise, sumbit the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this, more maintainable

```
var tmp = [$('#div_cl_fn'), $('#div_cl_ln'), $('#div_cl_ph'), $('#div_cl_mob')];

var i = -1;
while (++i < tmp.length)
{
    if (!isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_mob'), tmp[i]))
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        break;
    }
}
```

If you want to add something to check, just add an entry into the array

Or

```
for (var i in toCheck = [$('#div_cl_fn'),
                         $('#div_cl_ln'),
                         $('#div_cl_ph'),
                         $('#div_cl_mob')])
{
    if (!isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_mob'), toCheck[i]))
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: my question is not very last item my item is lets the user have filled all the textfields but left empty one in the middle the condition would be true because there would be some textfields are filled if you know what i mean... thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following

```
    var formSubmit1, formSubmit2, formSubmit3, formSubmit4;
    formSubmit1 = isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_fn'), $('#div_cl_fn'));
    formSubmit2 = isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_ln'), $('#div_cl_ln'));
    formSubmit3 = isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_ph'), $('#div_cl_ph'));
    formSubmit4 = isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_mob'), $('#div_cl_mob'));

    if(!formSubmit1 || !formSubmit2 || !formSubmit3 || !formSubmit4){
        event.preventDefault();
    }else{
        alert('formSubmit successfully');
    }
```

Comment: I've got about 30 fields to verify i need to look at the loop i guess....  or do you have any good idea?

Answer (score 2):

You should use it like

```
formSubmit = isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_fn'), $('#div_cl_fn'));
formSubmit = formSubmit && isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_ln'), $('#div_cl_ln'));
formSubmit = formSubmit && isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_ph'), $('#div_cl_ph'));
formSubmit = formSubmit && isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_mob'), $('#div_cl_mob'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...
You can do it in single line...

```
formSubmit = isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_fn'), $('#div_cl_fn')) && isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_ln'), $('#div_cl_ln')) &&  isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_ph'), $('#div_cl_ph')) && isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_mob'), $('#div_cl_mob'))
```

in this, it will check first one condition and if it is true then It will check further condition  otherwise it will take you out.

Answer (score 1):

All validation will be executed.

```
$(function(){

    var formValid,
        isValid = function(test_obj, element){
        if(!test_obj.val().length > 0){
            element.addClass('has-error');
        }else{
            element.removeClass('has-error');
            formValid = true;
        }
    };
    $('#rta_parties_form').submit(function(event){

        var formSubmit;
        formValid = false;

        isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_fn'), $('#div_cl_fn'));
        isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_ln'), $('#div_cl_ln'));
        isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_ph'), $('#div_cl_ph'));
        isValidToggle($('#rta_cl_mob'), $('#div_cl_mob'));

        if(!formValid){
            event.preventDefault();
        }else{
            alert('formSubmit successfully');
        }


    });
});
```

Comment: Mr Johannes `isValidToggle()` is basically `isValid()` but it is not working here on my side any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much everyone but I got what I wanted I'm putting this code here for if anyone else wants to get use of the code in future...

```
$(function(){

    //below is one way using function
    var isValid = function(test_obj, element){
        if(!test_obj.val().length > 0){
            element.addClass('has-error');
            return false;
        }else{
            element.removeClass('has-error');
            return true;
        }
    };

    $('#rta_parties_form').submit(function(event){

        var formSubmit = [];

        formSubmit[0] = isValid($('#rta_cl_fn'), $('#div_cl_fn'));
        formSubmit[1] = isValid($('#rta_cl_ln'), $('#div_cl_ln'));
        formSubmit[2] = isValid($('#rta_cl_ph'), $('#div_cl_ph'));
        formSubmit[3] = isValid($('#rta_cl_mob'), $('#div_cl_mob'));

        var validForm = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < formSubmit.length; i++) {
            if(formSubmit[i] == false){
                validForm = false;
            }
        };

        if(!validForm){
            event.preventDefault();
        }else{
            alert('formSubmit successfully');
        }

    });

});
```

This works fine for me, thanks to everyone one more time for your help..